# PHP: Can't Set Cookie

Tags: php, cookies

For some reason, I can't seem to set a cookie in one of my PHP files. All of the code works fine, except it refuses to set the cookie. I've placed different versions of cookie setting with different arguments, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. On top of that, I can set a cookie using that same line of code in a separate PHP file in the same directory. I've tried placing setcookie() at different places and I still get the same result. Am I missing something?

```
<?php
$table_name="lfgs";
$name=$_POST['name'];
$event="[";
$level=$_POST['level'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$hours=$_POST['hours']*60*60;
$minutes=$_POST['minutes']*60;
$time=$hours+$minutes+time();

setcookie("remember", $name, $time, 'www.domain.com', '/');

if(isset($_POST['event'])){
    if (is_array($_POST['event'])) {
        foreach($_POST['event'] as $value){
            $event = $event . "\"" . $value . "\",";
        }
    } else {
        $value = $_POST['event'];
        $event = $event . "\"" . $value . "\"]";
    }
} else {
    $event = "";
}

if($event[strlen($event)-1] == ',') {
    $event = substr_replace($event ,"]",-1);
}

$con=mysqli_connect("domain.com","username","password","database");

$req="INSERT INTO $table_name(name, event, level, comments, time) VALUES ('$name', '$event', '$level', '$comments', '$time')";
mysqli_query($con,$req);

mysqli_close($con);

foreach($_COOKIE as $c) {
    echo $c . "<br />";
}
?>
```

**Edit:** This is ALL the code for the entire file.

Comment: Have you tried following the cookies in the developer tools in chrome or firefox ?

Comment: The cookie doesn't ever show up. Like the call was ignored. Chrome's dev tools say there are no cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the php reference, the correct way to use the `setcookie` function is

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

Didn't you swaped the $path and $domain argument?

Try

```
setcookie("remember", $name, $time, '/', 'www.domain.com');
```

Comment: That did it. It must be too late.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
setcookie("remember", $name, '/', $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont't understand what you want to do, but it'll not works the way you do.
**Always remember**: you work with PHP on the **server side**. 
So to set a cookie an then to test if it worked, you need always tow steps (because you are on the server side):
The first step is to set the cookie.
And then during the **next** request you can check if ur cookie contains in the global $_COOKIE array. if yes then ok, if not then mybe the client/user donsen't allow to set cookies.

If you need to do it in "one step", you should use JavaScript. Something like that:
On submit the form, set the cookie and then propagate the submit action (send the data to the server). JQuery support a good solution to set and read cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the php interpreter doesn't send a char before the `setcookie()` call for some reason? The function send a HTTP header, so it have to appear before any printing on the page.

Comment: Unless the $_POST variable could be affecting it, what you see is all of the code for the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, if you have any session active on the page it will not allow you to create PHP cookies. Start a new blank page and test it that way.

You should be able to set a cookie on the new generic page. Then go back to your other page that has a session started on it. Echo the details of that set cookie in the session page and you will get the stored value, no problem.

You can call cookies but you can't seem to create them in an active session page. At least, I can't with my current system settings/config.