# How to set cookie in php 7.0. Set Cookie not working in PHP

Tags: php

I want to set cookie in my PHP project my code is

```
setcookie("gi_cur", "USD", time() + (8886400 * 130), "/");
```

but this is not working.... currently I use PHP version 7.0
Can someone please help me 
Thanks

Comment: i used Godaddy shared hosting and this code work fine but now i just upgrade to VPS from another hosting and this code not working....

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working". Any errors ? Unwanted behaviour?

Comment: kindly check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970754/why-are-my-cookies-not-setting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Can't Set Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557052/php-cant-set-cookie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value = "" [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path = "" [, string $domain = "" [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )

<?php
$value = 'something from somewhere';

setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
?>
```